# How can I disable the auto reloading of a server side Ag Grid?

Tags: ag-grid, reload, server-side

How can I disable the auto reloading of a server side Ag Grid?

In my case I have the columns which get generated in runtime depending on what was returned in a first call of the `getRows`. After the first `getRows` call I run the `api.setColumnDefs` which triggers one more `getRows` call. I want to avoid that the second call of the `getRows`.

Another case when I do not want the reload to happen automatically is when I set the returned by BE values for filters, i.e. the `api.getFilterInstance(colId).setFilterValues(values)` or when I destroy a few filters with the `api.destroyFilter(colId)` - in this case BE gets a separate request for each `destroyFilter` which is not usable at all.

[Here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/server-side-model-datasource/#getrows) is the server side rendering documentation I am talking about.